# pandas add columns to one DF from another without merge

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have

```
DF1=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]], columns=['a','b','c'])
DF2=pd.DataFrame([[9,8,7]],columns=['x','y','z'])
```

I want to add all the columns of DF2 to DF1 but I want to repeat the rows of DF2 to fill all the rows of DF1

I can think of 3 ways to do it, none of them seem satisfactory.

With a for loop, one column at a time

```
for col in ['x','y','z']:
    DF1[col]=DF2[col]
```

Creating a dummy column and then merging the two against that dummy variable

```
DF1=DF1.assign(dummy=1).merge(DF2.assign(dummy=1)).drop('dummy',axis=1)
```

which is faster (with my real data) than the for loop but looks really weird.

Creating a new DF2 with rows equal to DF1's rows:

```
DF1[['x','y','z']]=pd.concat([DF2 for x in range(DF1.shape[0])])
```

This one errors out saying `cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels` but it doesn't really matter because just the `pd.concat([DF2 for x in range(DF1.shape[0])])` is disqualifying slow.

Is there a syntax that's more like this but that actually works and is better than the merge?

```
DF1['x','y','z']=DF2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
DF1[DF2.columns] = DF2
DF1 = DF1.fillna(method = "ffill")
```

Or

```
DF1[DF2.columns] = DF2.loc[[0]*3, :].values
```

You can (dinamically) change the `3` for the size of `DF1`.

Comment: can you restrict the fillna to just the new columns?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor You could do something like `DF1[DF2.columns] = DF1[DF2.columns].fillna(method = "ffill")` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for a cross join?

```
DF1.join(DF2, how='cross')
```

this is roughly equivalent to `pd.concat([DF1,DF2], axis=1).ffill().astype(int)`

Output

```
   a  b  c  x  y  z
0  1  2  3  9  8  7
1  2  3  4  9  8  7
2  3  4  5  9  8  7
```

Comment: It would appear so.